# Break a inner loop in 2 nested loop if a statement is fulfilled

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop

I have written the following code I want to break the loop of m, but want to continue the loop of i if the (if) statement returns true

```
For i = 7 To lastrow
    For m = 33 To 37

        If IsNumeric(mmk.Sheets("FG").Cells(i, m)) = True Then
            quote(i, m) = mmk.Sheets("FG").Cells(i, m)
        End If

        If quote(i, m) <> Empty And quote(i, m) <> 0 And quote(i, m) > 0 Then
            row(i, m) = i
        End If

       row1(i) = row(i, m)

       If row1(i) <> Empty And row1(i) <> 0 And row1(i) > 0 Then
           mmk.Sheets("FG").Rows(row1(i)).Select
           Selection.Copy
           wrk.Activate
           wrk.Sheets("Nego").Activate

           With ActiveSheet
               last1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
           End With

           wrk.Sheets("Nego").Cells(last1 + 1, 1).Select
           ActiveSheet.Paste
           Exit For
           Next i
        Else
           Next m
           Next i
        End If
```

I want the outer loop to continue but the inner loop to break if the last if statement turns true

the problem is in the following expression

```
exit for
next i
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a matter of checking in the right place if your exit condition is true.
Exiting the inner loop should happen within the inner loop.

```
Sub BreakInnerLoops()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer

For i = 1 To 10
    For j = 1 To 10
        For k = 1 To 10
            Debug.Print i & " " & j & " " & k
            If k = 5 Then Exit For 'Exits k loop.
        Next k
        If j = 5 Then Exit For 'Exits j loop.
    Next j
    If i = 5 Then Exit For 'Exits i loop.
Next i

End Sub
```

In your case:

```
For i = 7 To lastrow 
    For m = 33 To 37
        'Some lines here.
        If row1(i) <> Empty And row1(i) <> 0 And row1(i) > 0 Then 'Exit condition and do stuff.
            mmk.Sheets("FG").Rows(row1(i)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            wrk.Activate
            wrk.Sheets("Nego").Activate
            With ActiveSheet
                last1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
            End With
            wrk.Sheets("Nego").Cells(last1 + 1, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Exit For
        End If
    Next m
Next i
```

Also you might want to read [how to avoid select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)